# When I insert PNG image using Image Asset , it turns to grey . How can I insert coloured image with different sizes?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

**When I insert PNG image into Image Asset , it turns to grey . How can I insert coloured image with different sizes?**

Comment: PNGs are not colored gray when inserted by default.  Post the image and the code you're using to access it.

Answer (score 1):

**Image Asset:** I use it to make my app icon not for add images so if you want the easiest way to add an image with any type "png, jpg,..."  just copy it and paste it in `src/drawble` "not advanced but work fine"

**Tip:** be sure the ImageView or the View which will display the image not colorful "as gray"

Answer (score -1):

You can always add whatever image you want through the explorer (or finder in Mac).

I like to use [Image Baker](https://www.img-bak.in/). You upload the image you want multiple sizes of there and you get a zip file that you can extract directly in your project (/app/src folder).